# How to use second table to assign dummy variable?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two data sets. One is a multiple-variables one including an id variable (more than one entry have the same id), the second is vector of distinct id numbers.

I want to update the first data set assigning value 1 if the entry has an id that is in the second dataset.

Is merging the two the best way to do this?
Or is there a way such as

```
UPDATE `directory.dataset_1`
SET dummy = IF(id IN dataset_2.id =1,1, 0)
WHERE TRUE;
```

If the problem would have been solved in R a toy example would be:

```
dataset_1 <- 
data.frame(c("000","001","010","011","000"),c("a","b","c","d","e"))
names(dataset_1) <- c("id","other")

dataset_2 <- data.frame(c("000","001"))
names(dataset_2) <- c("id")

result <- data.frame(c("000","001","010","011","000"),c("a","b","c","d","e"), 
c(1,1,0,0,1))
names(result) <- c("id","other","dummy")
```

Comment: In BigQuery, datasets contain tables.  I simply have no idea what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Yes, the two data sets in questions are both table. I am trying to update the first table. I have no idea how to provide a toy example in sql please see the provided example in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic need to go in the WHERE not in the SET, try the below

(Note: I'm unsure from your script if the ID needs to be =1 in dataset_2, so remove the WHERE from the sub query if not);

```
    UPDATE dataset_1
    SET dummy = 1
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID
                    FROM dataset_2
                    WHERE ID = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, for the record, I removed the "WHERE ID = 1" part.